# Preferred Sequence Algorithm in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, sequence

**EXPLANATION**

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I need to write algorithm to decide sequence of producing products depending on their setup times.

What I mean: for example we need to produce 4 products: A B C D

I have a matrix (table `Changeover`) filled with setup times of each product like that:

```
Xasis   Yasis   Time
--------------------
A       B       10
A       C       15
A       D       5
B       A       5
B       C       20
B       D       10
C       A       10
C       B       15
C       D       5
D       A       0
D       B       5
D       C       25
```

Rules:

- If first we produce product A, and after we'll produce product B, there will be a 10 minute setup time...
- If first we produce product A, and after we'll produce product C, there will be a 15 minute setup time...
- If first we produce product B, and after we'll produce product A, there will be a 5 minute setup time...

and so on....

Desired output:

Goal is to make sequence of producing products with shortest time. So with this sample data It would be:

```
   5       0       10      (Total 15 minutes)
C ----> D ----> A ----> B
```

This output is incorrect:

```
   15      10      0       (Total 25 minutes)
C ----> B ----> D ----> A
```

I have another table `Products` with data like that:

```
Product    Rank
A          1
B          2
C          3
D          4
```

Rank value in table `Products` tells sequence of producing products, so with this sample sequence would be:

```
   10      20      5       (Total 35 minutes)
A ----> B ----> C ----> D
```

So it's incorrect, because total setup time is 35 minutes.

Desired results: I need algorithm to update the `Products` table like that:

```
Product    Rank
A          3
B          4
C          1
D          2

   5       0       10      (Total 15 minutes)
C ----> D ----> A ----> B
```

Do you have any ideas how this could be done? (for real there are over 140 products)

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Attr
(
    Id NVARCHAR(20),
    [Rank] INT
)

INSERT INTO #Attr (Id, [Rank]) 
VALUES ('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3), ('D',4)

CREATE TABLE #Change
(
    Xasis NVARCHAR(20),
    Yasis NVARCHAR(20),
    [Time] INT
)

INSERT INTO #Change (Xasis, Yasis, [Time]) 
VALUES ('A','B',10), ('A','C',15), ('A','D',5),
       ('B','A',5), ('B','C',20), ('B','D',10),
       ('C','A',10), ('C','B',15), ('C','D',5),
       ('D','A',0), ('D','B',5), ('D','C',25);
```

What I've tried: I can get lowest setup time of each group in following:

```
WITH filtered AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Xasis ORDER BY [Time]) AS RankPerGroup
    FROM #Change AS c
)
SELECT 
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Time]) AS [Rank]
FROM filtered f1
WHERE RankPerGroup = 1
```

And I got following output:

```
Xasis   Yasis   Time    RankPerGroup    Rank
D       A       0       1               1
A       D       5       1               2
B       A       5       1               3
C       D       5       1               4
```

Which is incorrect that because I can't produce in that sequence:

```
    0       D already produced, so that's incorrect
D ----> A --X--> D ---
```

Hope I explained It clear, If you have any questions or misunderstood me, just ask me I'll provide more information.

Comment: I think that your problem can be modeled by a directed graph and finding the shortest bath between two nodes. [Shortest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Answer (score 1):

If you have four products you can do:

```
select co1.Xasis as x1, co2.Xasis as x2, co3.Xasis as x3, co3.Yasis as x4,
       (co1.time + co2.time + co3.time) as total_time
from changeover co1 join
     changeover co2
     on co1.Yasis = co2.Xasis join
     changeover co3 
     on co2.Yasis = co3.Xasis
where col2.Xasis not in (col1.Yasis) and
      col3.Xasis not in (col1.Yasis, col2.Yasis) and
      col3.Yasis not in (col1.Xasis, col2.Xasis, col3.Xasis)
order by total_time desc;
```

This is implementing a brute force algorithm in SQL.  In general, this is the best you can do with a single query.

The `join`s are guaranteeing that the sequence is possible.  The `not in` guarantee that new links in the chain do not return to a previous product.

If you have more products, you can either customize the query for the number of products that you have.  Alternatively, you can set up a recursive subquery.  However, I would be careful.  By the time you get around 10 products, this will probably become prohibitively expensive.

For a large problem, you might want to look at other types of optimization algorithms (which would probably be approximate), using a graph database or advanced analytic software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I mentioned in questions `(For real there are over 140 products)`, so what could be done in that way?

Comment: Have you tested It with my sample data? After editing no rows selected, before editing (with cross join) returned data, but not correctly, that was like all possible combinations. If I'm using WHERE clause like that: `where co1.Xasis not in (co2.Xasis, co3.Xasis, co3.Yasis) and
   co2.Xasis not in (co1.Yasis, co1.Xasis, co3.Xasis, co3.Yasis) and
   co3.Xasis not in (co1.Xasis, co2.Xasis, co1.Yasis, co2.Yasis, co3.Yasis)` It eliminate duplicate products from columns, but still lowest total_time incorrect. And maybe there are more dynamic way If I have over 100 products..?

Comment: How about recursive subquery? If there are over 100 products, It would work normally? Could you help me with that?

Comment: @Infinity . . . It is not worth the effort of explaining.  Even if you have only two "next" products per product, then 2^140 combinations is too many to handle in the database (see the reference to "10" in my answer).  Time to hire a specialist.  You have a very hard optimization problem.